# JFrame nesting layouts exception in thread error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, panels

So I'm nesting multiple layouts, these layouts are FlowLayout inside of BorderLayout which goes inside of a Card layout. The reason I have so many Layouts is because I use FlowLayout to align the components in a panel. This panel is then added to my main frame using BorderLayout and I align this using `.NORTH` etcetera. I then add this panel (The one containing the the FlowLayout inside of the BorderLayout) to a card which will allow me to switch between panels.

When I add the panels to the cards I can't run the program and get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.0.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Computer Science Projects\PE Fixtures v2.0\out\production\PE Fixtures v2.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.0.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: unknown constraint: 2
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.java:463)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.java:424)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1120)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
    at Main.createAndShowGUI(Main.java:48)
    at Main.access$000(Main.java:8)
    at Main$2.run(Main.java:77)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

CODE:

```
import javafx.geometry.HorizontalDirection;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Main
    {
        String[] columns = {"Sport", "Location", "Date", "Result"};
        String[][] data = {{"Football", "AQA Highschool", "12.11.13", "5 - 0"},
                {"Tennis", "Wembley", "26.11.14.", "TBC"}};

        private void createAndShowGUI()
        {
            CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

            JPanel guestCard = new JPanel(layout);
            JPanel guestTitle = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));               //GUEST TOP PANEL
            JLabel fixturesLabel = new JLabel("FIXTURES");
            fixturesLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 50));
            fixturesLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            guestTitle.add(fixturesLabel);
            JTable fixturesTable = new JTable(data, columns)                                 //GUEST MID PANEL
            {
                public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            fixturesTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(350, 450));
            fixturesTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(fixturesTable);
            JPanel guestBot = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));                  //GUEST BOT PANEL
            JButton loginButtonGuest = new JButton("Login");
            guestBot.add(loginButtonGuest);



            JPanel loginCard = new JPanel(layout);                                           //LOGIN TOP PANEL
            JPanel loginTitle = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("LOGIN");
            loginLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 50));
            loginLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            loginTitle.add(loginLabel);

            JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8,8));                           //ADDS CARDS TO CONTAINER
            container.add(guestCard, "2");
            container.add(loginCard, "3");

            guestCard.add(guestTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);                                  //ADDS COMPONENTS TO CARDS
            guestCard.add(scrollTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            guestCard.add(guestBot, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            loginCard.add(loginTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            container.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);                                       //COLOURS CARDS
            guestTitle.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            scrollTable.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            guestBot.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

            layout.show(container, "1");

            JFrame window = new JFrame("PE Fixtures");                                      //CREATES WINDOW
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.getContentPane().add(container);
            window.setSize(400, 700);
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setResizable(false);
            window.setVisible(true);

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new Main().createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now fixed it. I just made the border layout go within the cards, I had it vice versa.